# How to create a new word document with page and comments?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to use VBA to create a new document containing the pages with comments from a document. I only found this macro creating a document listing out only comments. I need the page with the comment. How to modify it? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub PrintOnlyComments()
Dim oThisDoc As Document
Dim oThatDoc As Document
Dim c As Comment
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iPage As Integer

Set oThisDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oThatDoc = Documents.Add

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In oThisDoc.Comments
    'Find page number of comment
    oThisDoc.Select
    c.Reference.Select
    iPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

    'Put info in new document
    oThatDoc.Select
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    sTemp = "Page: " & iPage
    Selection.TypeText Text:=sTemp
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    sTemp = "[" & c.Initial & c.Index & "] " & c.Range
    Selection.TypeText Text:=sTemp
    Selection.TypeParagraph
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe do you want a template? `.docm` extension I mean .http://filext.com/file-extension/DOCM

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is my program if anyone is interested:

```
Sub PrintOnlyComments()

Dim oThisDoc As Document
Dim oThatDoc As Document
Dim c As Comment
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iPage As Integer
Dim iPage0 As Integer


Set oThisDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oThatDoc = Documents.Add
iPage0 = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In oThisDoc.Comments
  'Find page number of comment
   oThisDoc.Select
   c.Reference.Select
   iPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

   'paste the page to a new document
    If iPage <> iPage0 Then
     Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, iPage
     Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Copy
     oThatDoc.Activate
     Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
     Selection.EndKey
     Selection.Paste
    End If

    iPage0 = iPage
   Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```